# How to check which image was used in a GitLab runner when a command fails?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a multistage CI/CD setup which uses the default image (the runner is hosted on my server).

I need one stage to use a specific image (a MQTT client to send a single MQTT message but it does not really matter):

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - backend
  - frontend
  - reload

# backends deployment

googlecalendar:
  stage: backend
  script:
    - docker build -t dash-googlecalendar -f backends/googlecalendar/Dockerfile backends

(... there are other builds at the backend stage here ...)

# frontend deployment

frontend:
  stage: frontend
  script:
    - docker build -t dash-frontend -f frontend/Dockerfile frontend
(...)

# MQTT message

reload:
  stage: reload
  image: efrecon/mqtt-client
  script:
    - pub -h mqtt.mydomain -t dash/reload -m "`date`"
```

Everything runs smoothly until the `reload` stage:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.2.0 (a987417a)
  on srv zN2MsS9q
Using Shell executor...
Running on srv...
Fetching changes...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/zN2MsS9q/0/wsw70-docker/dash/.git/
Checking out 7d19cb65 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ pub -h mqtt.mudomain -t dash/reload -m "`date`"
bash: line 82: pub: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

`pub` is not recognized as a command in this image. But it does exist there, since the following command is successful:

```
docker run --init -it --rm efrecon/mqtt-client pub -h mqtt.mydomain -t dash/reload -m "`date`"
```

It is also successful if I start a `bash` and run `pub` from there.

All this leads me to wondering whether the image `efrecon/mqtt-client` is actually used in that stage. How could I check that?

Bonus question: if the image is correctly used, what could have gone wrong with the `pub` command?

Comment: What happens when you put the full file path to where `pub` is in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? ie `/usr/local/bin/pub` or wherever it is?

Comment: @Rekovni: good idea, but the error is the same (`bash: line 82: /usr/local/bin/pub: No such file or directory` and `pub` is indeed at `/usr/local/bin`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `efrecon/mqtt-client` image is not used for the reload job, since it is using the `shell` runner as stated on line 3 of the jobs output:

`Using Shell executor...`

It would seem your runner is configured as just a [shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) and should be configured as [docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) as well.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. Your answer made me rethink my whole setup - I realized that I am running the commands available on the host running the runner, no docker images are used at all. I will consider switching to the docker executor but this will bring some issues in accessing the `docker-compose` configurations I was accessing via the `-f` switch.